# fixeddocument to pdf by pdfsharp 1.32

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, fixeddocument

I want to save the fixeddocument to pdf file in wpf c#4.0, I use *pdfsharp* version 1.32，it has no Xps module, how can I transfer to pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC the latest PDFsharp version that included the XPS code was 1.31 (or was it 1.30?).

Take the source code of PDFsharp 1.32 and copy the XPS code from the older version. This should require little or no changes.

Comment: Thanks, i will try. I found some websites says there's some issues for 1.31 xps

Comment: I tried that，it works，but I found the text "-" missed when Xps to pdf. It's wired, because some "-" are shown normally, some are shown in the wrong position and some missed.  This scenario happens when the label' text is "-", no other characters. I found no reason...it's hard to understand the whole code, can you help me? Do you have the stable version? Thanks for your help